Can't boot after moving/resizing all partitions
I originally had Garuda Linux installated and wanted to move to rhel. First I split my nvme in half and installed fedora, but later reinstalled and wanted to try rocky. I installed rocky Linux 9 on the other partition(with lvm, I think separate boot location).
Now I wanted to move fully to rocky, so I booted a fedora live image, and with kde partition manager deleted old Linux btrfs partition, moved my rocky partitions left and resized the home lvm.
How nvme partitions looked Before:
|Garuda Boot| |Garuda| |RL Boot I think?| |Rocky LVM| |No clue|
Then I moved around everything to:
|RL boot?| |Rocky LVM| |idk|
Rocky LVM has 2 I think called volumes, root and home. Resized those too.
Now my pc won't boot. In bios I only see Fedora partition, which is the probably remnant boot, which is putting me into grub>.
I then in grub did
> ls
(Memdisk) (Proc) (Lvm/rl-root) (Lvm/rl-home) (Lvm/rl-swap) (Hd0) (Hd0,gpt6) (Hd0,gpt5) (Hd0,gpt4) (Hd0,gpt3)

//Prolly means separate boot part?
> ls (lvm/rl-root)/boot
./ ../

>Ls (Hd0,gpt3)/
Error: unknown file system

>Ls (Hd0,gpt4)/
Efi/ grub2/ loader/ vmlinuz...El9_4.x86_64 initramfs...el9_4 config-5... Symvers-5... 

>set root (Hd0,gpt4)
>linux /vmlinuz-5.14.0-427.33.1.el9_4.x86_64 root=/dev/nvme0p4
>Initrd /initramfs-5.14.0-427.33.1.el9_4.x86_64.img
>boot

Then I saw Linux penguins appear, some fly by text and then I end up in what I only can assume is that command that live watches IO changes, it just sits and tells me what usb devices are changing, not progressing or reacting to ctrl-c.
I REAALLY don't want to reinstall, took me months gradually to install everything I need for my work.
Unsure if that's the right Linux params, so I tried
linux ...x86_64 root=/dev/nvme0p4
And
linux ...x86_64 root=/dev/nvme0p6
But both resulted in just that usb logging state.
When I tried without setting the root, I Got
FAILED] Failed to start Switch Root.

See 'systemctl status initrd-switch-root.service' for details.

Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"

Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.

Type "journalctl" to view system logs.

and then again usb logging. Here I could ctrl-c, and doing ls I found out that I don't know what partition it is, but it's missing my home.
How can I rescue this?
I feel like I'm close, I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Edit1: following https://0xcaffee.blog/posts/grub-booting-with-lvm/ I managed to get to rocky Linux emergency console I think. Unfortunately default.target doesn't work, and I can't enter my root password due to it requiring characters from non-en layout(not that I'd know what to type once I'm in anyways).
It failed with:
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
[DEPEND]Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Mark the need to relabel after reboot.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/E804-AFGE.

edit2:
I used rEFInd to boot into the rocky linux iso, but still getting this switch root error. The /sysroot directory is empty. I assume I need to mount my lvm /rl-root manually to sysroot and retry boot? how can I do this? lvdisplay, rpm install lvm2, none of these commands work in emergency mode. and I can’t just mount an lvm partition, cause mount /dev/nvme0n1p6 /sysroot gives error unknown filesystem 'LVM2_member'
edit3:
>lvm
>vgchange -ay
(volumes now active)
>exit
>mount /dev/dm-2 /sysroot
>mount /dev/dm-1 /sysroot/home
>exit

[236.185754] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/mapper/rl-swap.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/mapper/rl-swap.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swaps.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/E084-AF6E.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/E084-AF6E.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Mark the need to relabel after reboot. [ TIME] Timed out waiting for device /dev/mapper/rl-home.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/mapper/rl-home.
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalct1 -xb" to view

